# How can I sort a list of file names by some substring of the name?

Tags: filenames, sort

I have a number of files with names like:

```
beginning_num1_734_num2_1.363e+12_num3_800.pdf
beginning_num1_735_num2_7.453e+13_num3_800.pdf
beginning_num1_1007_num2_9.453e+12_num3_1200.pdf
```

I'd like to be able to sort a list of these filenames by the various `num`s, and pass the sorted list to various command line utilities. For example, if I were sorting by `num2`, I'd want the order:

```
beginning_num1_734_num2_1.363e+12_num3_800.pdf
beginning_num1_1007_num2_9.453e+12_num3_1200.pdf
beginning_num1_735_num2_7.453e+13_num3_800.pdf
```

I have a python script to do this, but it seems like it *should* be possible with nothing but filters like `sed` and `sort`.

Is there any easy way to sort by parts of a file name, using only common command line filters?

Comment: I think the trick can be done in awk, are + _ and . the only valid separators in this case?

Comment: @vfbsilva: `+` isn't a separator, `num2` is a floating point number.

Comment: please point expected input and output so people can craft better.

Comment: @vfbsilva: Done.

Comment: Ok I still confuse  about waht you want so I did a draft solution, basically I think you will use a mix of awk and sort. 
sort -g sorts by absolute numeric value, I assume if yo uuse awk to get the subfield of your interest you can use sort -g to get the desired order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GNU `sort` with the `-g(--general-numeric-sort)` option should be able to do the trick

```
sort -k5,5g -t '_'  <<!
beginning_num1_734_num2_1.363e+12_num3_800.pdf
beginning_num1_735_num2_7.453e+13_num3_800.pdf
beginning_num1_1007_num2_9.453e+12_num3_1200.pdf
!
beginning_num1_734_num2_1.363e+12_num3_800.pdf
beginning_num1_1007_num2_9.453e+12_num3_1200.pdf
beginning_num1_735_num2_7.453e+13_num3_800.pdf
```

Comment: What does the `-k5,5g` do?

Comment: Ah! The `-k` denote which fields in the string to use, `g` is general numeric sort, and `-t '_'` is to use the underscore as a seperator. Brilliant!